# Audio files in Java/Android Wear are not playing after saving to External Storage

Tags: java, file, wear-os, fileinputstream

I have recorded an audio in the Android wear document directory (which is accessible after watch restart). When I export the file to external storage of the watch which is accessible by file manager apps, the audio file does not open and I assume it is not saved correctly. I assume this is more a Java problem than Android Wear.

This is how I export the file:

This is the saved file which is not opening in Audio Players:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B38VWNq67cFHUGF3UTZKVkp0Ym5QeGhvZTdLelRLZ1Y2OThv)

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.file_name_input);
        name.setText("a.pcm");


        //Copy files
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                .getExternalStorageState())) {

            File outFile = new File(
                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    fileName);

            if (!outFile.exists())
                copyImageToMemory(outFile);
        }
    }

    // Copy file methods
    private void copyImageToMemory(File outFile) {
        try {

            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(outFile));
BufferedInputStream(openFileInput(test.getName()));
            FileInputStream in = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;

            in = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);

            copy(bis, os);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAGFILE, "FileNotFoundException");
        }
    }
```

This is how the recording and file creation has been done:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mState = State.RECORDING;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDING_RATE, CHANNEL_IN, FORMAT, BUFFER_SIZE * 3);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        try {
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    mContext.openFileOutput(mOutputFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            mAudioRecord.startRecording();
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                int read = mAudioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to record data: " + e);
        } finally {
            if (bufferedOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            mAudioRecord.release();
            mAudioRecord = null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mState = State.IDLE;
        mRecordingAsyncTask = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (mState == State.RECORDING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping the recording ...");
            mState = State.IDLE;
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Requesting to stop recording while state was not RECORDING");
        }
        mRecordingAsyncTask = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you add permission for external storage? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission

Comment: I added that but made no difference.